# Trying to access and print specific indices of an array using a list of the required index numbers

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, list-comprehension

I have an array of shape (8790,8) so a large list of information. I created a filter so I can access specific indices of this array. For example - my list is something like (79,2345,4544,6789,6790). I want to use this list to print the full corresponding indices in my original array. I tried this....

```
For i in finalList:
    if origArray[i][6] == choice:
        outputList.append(i)
        print(outputList)
```

I get TypeError: 'int' object not iterable.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including a Traceback, see [ask].

Comment: Do you want to print `i` if `row[i,6]` is an element of another list of numbers, say called `lst`? You could try `np.where(np.isin(origArray[:,6], lst))[0]` where `lst` is the list of numbers you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem must be the declaration of the variable `finalList`
This works fine

```
>>> finalList = (79,2345,4544,6789,6790)
>>> for i in finalList:
...   print(i)
...
79
2345
4544
6789
6790
```

Comment: Yep, finalList wasn't actually in a correct list configuration. Once I converted it, it worked fine. So thanks for that!